# Saving SignalR connection state with scaleout servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-backplane

Using SignalR 2.2.0, I would like some validation of observations concerning clients executing hub methods in a multi-server scale out setup.

I have SignalR running in a multi server model, using the SQL Server scaleout message bus.

When a client connects, the `OnConnected` method of the Hub is called, as expected.  I save the `Context.ConnectionId` in static dictionary.

When the client later calls a method of the hub, it seems that another server in the farm is executing the hub method and not the server that originally ran the OnConnected method. The `Context.ConnectionId` value in the hub method is correct, but it does not exist in the dictionary.

Is this the expected behaviour in the scale out model?  If so, then I assume that I should be saving connection state data in database so that all Hub on all the servers will be able to look up the connection state based on the ConnectionId.

Comment: Generally, storing shared information in a shared db is a way to go with scaleout model. But I don't see why you need to store connection state, the servers in signalR should care only about its `local` state, this information does not need to be shared. All we need is a backplane to transfer messages between servers. Do you have any specific requirements that need to share this information?

Comment: Let's say we have 3 users (1,2,3) connected to server1, 3 users (4,5,6) connected to server2. When the user 4 sends a message to user 1, the message goes from the user 4 => server 2 => backplane => server 1 => user 1. This also works if the user 1 connects to both servers (on different devices), in this case, both server1 and server2 respond to user 1 with different connection Ids which represent different devices or different browser tabs,.....without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the expected behaviour in the scale out model? If so, then I
>   assume that I should be saving connection state data in database so
>   that all Hub on all the servers will be able to look up the connection
>   state based on the ConnectionId.

Yes this is expected behaviour, you should use shared resource like database or cache. But connectionIds will be not enough by itself. Because a client will get different connectionIds on different servers or on refreshes. So you should map connectionId and client. When a disconnect occurs find client with connectionId and check this client has another connectionId.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36083770/3432471) I have answered more detail based on question.